# Convert Bitmap into Color[]

Tags: c#, arrays, bitmap

I have a bitmap that I want to convert into a color array, faster than if I had used the GetPixel function.

So far I have seen people convert the bitmap into a byte array first then into the color array:

```
Bitmap bmBit = (Bitmap)bit;

var bitmapData = bmBit.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmBit.Width, bmBit.Height),
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmBit.PixelFormat);
var length = bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height;
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, bytes, 0, length);
bmBit.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
```

But this returns a  bmBit with incorrect numbers.
What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to do this without converting to a byte array first?

Comment: Are you taking into account that the `Stride` property includes padding bytes?

Comment: what are "incorrect numbers" for you?

Comment: It returns the numbers with 0's incorrectly placed throughout the array.

Comment: Are those zeros the padding zeros? On the end of each of the `Stride` lengths of bytes?

Comment: It seems to occur in a pattern, so maybe I can just remove these zeros. I have a 3x3 bitmap and the zeros occur in sets of 3 every 9 bytes with 3 sets of 3 in total.

Comment: Check my answer. I'm assuming you have a 24 bit per pixel bitmap. All your rows of width 3 pixels are padded to 4 bytes. 3 * 3 bytes per pixel = 9 bytes, padding to 4 bytes = 12 bytes per row. That leaves you with 3 pixels and 3 pad bytes (the pad bytes are probably all 0).

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways for pixels to be stored in a bitmap (16 color, 256 color, 24 bits per pixel, etc...), and rows are padded to multiples of 4 bytes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bitmapData.Height; i++)
{
    //the row starts at (i * bitmapData.Stride).
    //we must do this because bitmapData.Stride includes the pad bytes.
    int rowStart = i * bitmapData.Stride;        

    //you need to use bitmapData.Width and bitmapData.PixelFormat
    //  to determine how to parse a row. 

    //assuming 24 bit. (bitmapData.PixelFormat == Format24bppRgb)
    if (bitmapData.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitmapData.Width; j++)
        {
            //the pixel is contained in:
            //    bytes[pixelStart] .. bytes[pixelStart + 2];
            int pixelStart = rowStart + j * 3;
        }
    }
}
```